# time compare php with sql

Tags: php, mysql, session

```
$ThatTime ="18:50:00";
    $time=$r['logintime'];
if (strtotime($time) >= strtotime($ThatTime)) {
  $query="UPDATE attendance SET att_status='Present' WHERE empid={$_SESSION['empid']}";
 $sql=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
}if (strtotime($time) <= strtotime($ThatTime)) {
  $query="UPDATE attendance SET att_status='Late' WHERE empid={$_SESSION['empid']}";
 $sql=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
}
```

i keep getting "late" on my database even thought i change my `$thattime` value.
i try to change the value, still get "late" on my database. i have `time` type on my `logintime` column.

can someone help me?

thanks.

Comment: is your mysql timezone same as yours?

Comment: same. date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jakarta');

Comment: how are you storing logintime?

Comment: why are you using equal to in both if condition , it will clash, just saying..

Comment: if user login, i will insert attendance in column logintime(time)= CURRENT_TIME()  and logindate(date)=CURRENT_DATE();

Comment: @GaurangSondagar i try to remove the "=", it still doesnt work.

Comment: where are ayou getting the date and time values? mysql or php?

Comment: @Vodka , i checked your code on fiddle and it's working fine.

Comment: maybe your if conditions are wrong. login time should be < = that time for present and > for late

Comment: @inarilo i get the date and time values from mysql database. if i change < = for present. it always present, never late, eventhought i change the $thattime. i already try that.

Comment: what do you get if you print out $time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have made a sample of your code to check,

```
<?php
$ThatTime ="18:50:00"; 
$time='18:49:00'; // use your db variable , i have used static for demo purpose
if (strtotime($time) > strtotime($ThatTime)) {
   // put your db query here
   echo 'Present';
}
if (strtotime($time) < strtotime($ThatTime)) {
   // put your second db query here
   echo 'Late';
}
if (strtotime($time) == strtotime($ThatTime)) {
   // put your second db query here
   echo 'Same Value';
}
?>
```

just place this code to check , if it echo present or late then put your query for update.

sorry , i forgot to add for equal to condition, make it as you like in equal to status.
hope this helps.

Comment: now my time is 21:20. then it must be "present", because im login at 21.12. but "late" stored in my database. 

my query is "$query="UPDATE attendance SET att_status='Late' WHERE empid={$_SESSION['empid']}";" and $time=$r['logintime'];

Comment: oh... sorry. you right. i just misplaced the code.  thanks for correction. you da best man!. :D